# Unable to get results in a row spreading across columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get reviews from a certain page of yelp.com. The scraper is doing it's job flawlessly. The results are also being written in a csv file successfully. There are 19 reviews available in that page. The results I'm having in 19 consecutive rows. However, I expect to get the results in 19 different columns instead.

This is the website link: [Link](https://www.yelp.com/biz/west-gate-veterinary-hospital-enterprise?adjust_creative=m9WJH6FDTC-8nW4jZRwtkw&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=m9WJH6FDTC-8nW4jZRwtkw)

To be clearer, results I'm having like:

```
1. review
2. review1
3. review2
4. review3
```

Results I expect to have:

```
A        B        C       D
review review1 review2 review3
```

This is my script:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open("new_file.csv","w",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

res = requests.get("use_above_link").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
for link in soup.select(".review-content"):
    review = [item.text for item in link.select("p")]
    print(review)
    writer.writerow(review)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution already. It should be like:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open("new_file.csv","w",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

res = requests.get("above_link").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
review = [item.text for item in soup.select(".review-content p")]
print(review)
writer.writerow(review)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to zip your array:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("new_csv_file",'w', newline="",encoding="UTF-8") as doc:
    writer = csv.writer(doc, delimiter=";")

    res = requests.get("use_above_link").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    for link in soup.select(".review-content"):
        reviews = [item.text for item in link.select("p")]
        z = zip(reviews)
        writer.writerow(z)
```

Comment: It's giving me the same results I'm already having with the above script. You perhaps noticed that I've explicitly mentioned `I expect to get the results in 19 different columns instead`.

Comment: I understood your desire. Infact, zipping an array solved the problem for me when I had it back in time. It was also an answer I saw on SO when I searched for a solution, so I am wondering why it doesn't work with your code.. Hower, glad you could get your code working! :)